# Query to select row with first occurrence of an element

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following SQL query from some data I'm trying to compile:

```
SELECT State, CountyName, Month, SUM(Sum_Confirmed) AS Max_Sum_Confirmed 
FROM `covid_by_countynmonth` 
GROUP BY State, Month 
ORDER BY State, Max_Sum_Confirmed DESC
```

It gives me the following table:

[image]

How can I have it so that it only shows the first record of each State?

I am wanting something like this (I got this by adding WHERE Month="July" but that was just for this example):
[image]

Comment: Probably the best answer uses a [Window Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), but that requires you are using MySQL 8.0. Are you?

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output data and your attempts to resolve the problem, and all that in readable form (that means text)

Comment: @turing042 - Do you want to have **Max_Sum_Confirmed** only from the first month like 21502 in your awaiting result or the sum of the state ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen yes I only want to display from the first month

Comment: @turing042 . . . Your query is malformed because `CountyName` is neither in the `GROUP BY` nor an argument to an aggregation function.

Comment: I added the tag [tag:greatest-n-per-group]. There are many posts with solutions in that tag, and your problem is of the same type, and should have a similar solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I have it so that it only shows the first record of each State?

Use window functions:

```
SELECT sm.*
FROM (SELECT State, Month,
             SUM(Sum_Confirmed) AS Max_Sum_Confirmed,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY State ORDER BY SUM(SUM_Confirmed) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM `covid_by_countynmonth` 
      GROUP BY State, Month 
     ) sm
WHERE seqnum = 1;
ORDER BY State, Max_Sum_Confirmed DESC ;
```

`CountyName` seems superfluous so I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample with both outputs: value from the Month and SUM from the State

```
SELECT
    c.State , c.CountyName
    , MONTHNAME(minMonth) as 'Month'
    , c.Sum_Confirmed -- SUM othe State der
    , f.Sum_Confirmed -- only from the first Month
      FROM (
      SELECT
          State, CountyName
        , MIN(str_to_date(`Month`,'%M')) as minMonth
        , SUM(Sum_Confirmed) as Sum_Confirmed
      FROM covid_by_countynmonth
      GROUP BY State
    ) AS c
LEFT JOIN covid_by_countynmonth AS f ON c.State = f.State AND f.`Month` = MONTHNAME(minMonth);
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [Bernd]> SELECT * FROM covid_by_countynmonth;
+----+-------+------------+---------+---------------+
| id | State | CountyName | Month   | Sum_Confirmed |
+----+-------+------------+---------+---------------+
|  1 | AR    | Arkansas   | July    |         21502 |
|  2 | AR    | Arkansas   | June    |         13244 |
|  3 | LA    | Acadia     | July    |         40500 |
|  4 | LA    | Acadia     | May     |         11997 |
|  5 | LA    | Acadia     | January |           999 |
+----+-------+------------+---------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.10 sec)

MariaDB [Bernd]> SELECT
    -> c.State , c.CountyName
    -> , MONTHNAME(minMonth) as 'Month'
    -> , c.Sum_Confirmed -- SUM othe State der
    -> , f.Sum_Confirmed -- only from the first Month
    ->   FROM (
    ->   SELECT
    ->       State, CountyName
    ->     , MIN(str_to_date(`Month`,'%M')) as minMonth
    ->     , SUM(Sum_Confirmed) as Sum_Confirmed
    ->   FROM covid_by_countynmonth
    ->   GROUP BY State
    -> ) AS c
    -> LEFT JOIN covid_by_countynmonth AS f ON c.State = f.State AND f.`Month` = MONTHNAME(minMonth);
+-------+------------+---------+---------------+---------------+
| State | CountyName | Month   | Sum_Confirmed | Sum_Confirmed |
+-------+------------+---------+---------------+---------------+
| AR    | Arkansas   | June    |         34746 |         13244 |
| LA    | Acadia     | January |         53496 |           999 |
+-------+------------+---------+---------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [Bernd]>
```

Answer (score -2):

Apparently this only works with postgresql.

Using DISTINCT ON to select for distinct values like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (COLUMN_OF_INTEREST) COLUMN_ALIAS, ...
```

Which then with the initial query becomes this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (SUB_.State) SUB_.State, SUB_.Month, SUB_.Max_Sum_Confirmed 
FROM (SELECT State, Month, SUM(Sum_Confirmed) AS Max_Sum_Confirmed 
FROM `covid_by_countynmonth` 
GROUP BY State, Month) AS SUB_ ORDER BY SUB_.State, SUB_.Max_Sum_Confirmed DESC
```

Comment: you cant get the first row with **DISTINCT**

Comment: @BerndBuffen this is not the first row, you can get the first row with limit = 1, this is the first record for a specific value

Comment: No, you must also give a **ORDER BY** , without the result is not guaranteed and in this sample the order is the monthname. so he must use **month(str_to_date(`Month`,'%b'))** to order it